# How to plot a line in a different colour to continue another plot? Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a question about plotting data in Matplotlib. How can I plot a line in a different colour to continue another line in Matplotlib (as shown below) to show a split in Training/Testing data or Current Price/Predicted Price?

[image]

I am using Python3 in Jupyter Notebook if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us the structure of your data? Like for example the last 10 datapoints from `train` and the first 10 datapoints from `test`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the training data and testing data into two and plot them in different colour in the same figure.

```
plt.plot(train_x, train_y, 'blue', test_x, test_y, 'orange')
plt.legend(["Train","Test"])
plt.show()
```